# Unable to use Wifi on Lenovo Z5070

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I bought new Lenovo Z5070 with a Core i5. However I am facing issues with my wireless: it goes away after sometime and then does not return until I reboot.

Comment: have you installed any power saver software recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83641#c1

"There is a new version of this driver at GitHub. You will need to have the package with the kernel headers installed.

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

This version of the driver will be submitted for inclusion in kernel 3.18. I ran it for 39 hours with no disconnects."

this solution works for me. I hope that help

**Note**

If You update the ubuntu, and this update has `ubuntu base` updates, so you need to run the following again.

```
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Thanks it's been 3 hours and still no issues .

Comment: it will work fine with you, but take care when you update ubuntu kernel .. it will override the one you install so you will need to set up it again .. I didn't find solution to this problem but it works fine .. I think we can wait until it becomes the official release

Comment: hope it gets rectified with next official release , Until then this is the savior , Else my laptop was more of a desktop due to ever necessary LAN cable

Comment: Thanks a ton Tareq Salahedeen. You saved my months or years !! This solution took only 20 secs for me to do this magic.