# Wifi disconnects and doesn't re-connect anymore

Tags: wireless, connection, disconnect

i've got a Lenovo z50-70 and when I connect to a wifi it works for some time and then internet stops working; when I manually disconnect it, it takes like a minute to disconnect and then it tries to reconnect again without success, all i can do is reboot. I read about some people with similar problems and I disabled IPV6 but the problem remains. I also tried different wifis but nothing changed and I have no problems on my windows partition. Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and I found this to be the most helpful by now.

[Unable to use Wifi on Lenovo Z5070](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549238/unable-to-use-wifi-on-lenovo-z5070)

It doesn’t work 100% of the time but at least I don't need to reboot every 2-3 hours.